# Xamarin WebClient for POST Requests extremely slow

Tags: c#, http, post, xamarin

When I try to make POST requests in Xamarin the time the function `GetRequestStream()` takes is 10-20 seconds. The answer time on my server is below 1 second and so is the POST request I made from a website.

I already tried:

- Setting proxy server to null so it won't look it up
- Using blocks around the requests so it get's flushed
- Increased the maximum connections
- Did everything with async multithreading
- Even tried another class called RestSharp - same result.

Nothing I did was actually helping to reduce the runtime even by 100 milliseconds. I just cannot imagine that this is Xamarins fault because I can't be the only one who decided to do some HTTP requests in his cross platform app. I already lost UWP since the ServiceManager, which I use to connect to TLS sites isn't supported in UWP - thank you Xamarin.

I really need solutions so please help :)

---

this is the code i used and optimized:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);
HttpWebRequest webRequest = new HttpWebRequest(uri);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Proxy = null;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Timeout = 1000;
webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000;
Stream dataStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
await dataStream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
     string ret = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
     return ret;
}
```

and this is the code i tried with the ModernHttpClient

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] q = query.Split('&');
for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
     values.Add(q[i].Split('=')[0], q[i].Split('=')[1]);
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
HttpResponseMessage response;
try
{
     response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
     string answer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     return answer;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     return "";
}
```

and of course i added these lines before calling the whole network stuff

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (a, b, c, d) => { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

---

It's definitely a Xamarin or an Android Problem. I don't have other devices to test it,but... what can i do now? I tested it on a .Net console application, so it's definitely not .Net related.

Comment: Did you try building the app and running the function on another device? It might be device-specific.

Comment: Have you tried to do the request to another server and check how much it takes to get the response?

Comment: it's definitely not a server thing because i already tested my server and it answers in 0.2s.
sadly i don't have any other device and those emulators just won't run too..

Comment: Can you give a little more information about your problem? What are you trying to do and what does your environment look like? Are you making an app, for example? Some more context might be helpful to people in a position to help you.

Comment: i'll tell you whatever you want ^^ since i said i'm using Xamarin it's ovious i'm developing an appp.

Comment: i have a tomcat server running who sends commands to my database. but i already measured the time the whole request takes and it's 0.2s so that's not the problem. 
i use SSL on Port 8443 and i'm usying a dynamic DNS server but i sent post requests on the dyndns server Too (btw its over dynv6 with ipv6 support) and there are no problems. so it's definitely on my client
I'm developing on C# and the first thing i do when starting the app is downloading the whole database which means Select * from each table and do insert into commands for every line i get so i can get a local database.

Comment: for measuring i used the Diagnostics.StopWatch and placed it around the one line with GetRequestStream() -> 10.000ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer!
it speeds up when i set the Protocol Version. It's mentione basically nowhere but i googled for android post slowdowns and there i found it, finally.
setting the protocol version to HTTP 1.1 speeds things up very fast!

now i just have to fix the boot delay with xamarin >.<

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Where did you set the protocol version to 1.1? Do you mean TLS 1.1, or another option somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Try implement [ModernHttpClientPlugin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient) into your code.

Just add this line when initializing new HttpClient, and everything should run smoother.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
```

Another idea is to try your implementation in new blank console aplication. Then you will see if this is problem with your server/client or Xamarin itself. It should look something like this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[]args)
    {
        MainAsync(null);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var query = "user=mickey&passwd=mini";
        string[] q = query.Split('&');
        for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
            values.Add(q[i].Split('=')[0], q[i].Split('=')[1]);

        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://www.example.com/login.php"), content);
            string answer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Please, give us feedback how fast that goes.

Comment: i'll add it tomorrow :) please stay tuned i'll post the update as soon as possible. I hope NuGet won't make problems.

Comment: okay that didn't end well. 21 seconds request time with this one >.> i don't think it's a matter of classes because i tried 3 different ones now... 
what could i do now?
is it really a Xamarin thing?

Comment: Can you provide us URL for that request? I have huge app written in Xamarin, and i can say that requests work pretty fast. Have you tried make identically request in Postman or Fiddler? Can you provide code that implements your HttpClient?

Comment: I will but it's a bit messy since i'm using a dynamic dns server from dynv6 and didn't configure that automatic update stuff plus it's not a commercial app so the server is just online for debugging.
but maybe you can share the post stuff too :) 
i made a request with hurl.it

Comment: Better use Fiddler or Postman, they are much more professional tools than hurl.it. For debugging mobile app i always use Fiddler because i can set proxy on my physical device/emulator and capture all network request that device is making. Try it, and you will never look back ;)

Comment: well as i said i'm not that professional it's just my first look into networks stuff and such problems are really bad for my learning effect XD all i learned is that i really hate Xamarin. 
i posted the code so pretty please help ^^
plus the focus's not really on my server. my server is working perfect, just as intended. it's just a bridge to my database, so i just send the database query to my server, or some login data and the server does the database stuff and then sends back the reply. 
i made my server use TLS because i wanted to practice PW stuff. but i tired turning it off already

Comment: I edited my post, try yours implementations in blank console application. Maybe it not fault of Xamarin at all and something goes wrong with .net itself. How much data you get in response?

Comment: the amount.. i got 5 columns: int, text, text, text, text. and i get 107 rows. i'll test your code at once.

Answer (score 0):

In my case 'WebClient' and 'HttpWebReuest' cause first-time delays about 20 secs (possible, during resolve of new hosts) on some specific Android 7 devices, but works good on others.

I tried different ways to solve this problem but for me only replacement to 'HttpClient' solves it.